# How to change dynamic the params of the get method

Tags: angular, api, parameters, get, angular7

I am trying to pass the search string to get method params from an input at search.component.html to search.service.ts
at service:
my params are:

```
  public params = new HttpParams().set('order', '0')
                                  .set('search', '')
                                  .set('batch', '1')
                                  .set('batchSize', '40');
```

my get method:

```
getObjects():: Observable<Array<objects>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<objects>>(this.apiUrl + 'Get', { params: this.params }).pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    );
```

at component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.data.getObjects()
  .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    this.objects = res;

  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to do that work? 
the user in my app want to search a  table, in the api we have done the get method with the above params('search' string). for two language.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code in your question looks correct (though not ideal) to me. If you want to send other values of parameters, then use, for example `.set('search', theValueEnteredByTheUser)` instead of `.set('search', '')`. Is that what you're asking? if not, what?

Comment: i tried but i couldn't pass this value from the component.ts to service.ts

Comment: So, is your question "how to write a form and get the value entered in the form in Angular"? If that is your question, it's too broad: there's a whole chapter about it in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview. If that's not your question, then what is it? What concrete problem are you facing? WHat is the code you tried?

Comment: i made the input to object,component.html and i got it to object.component.ts but how i can pass this value to object.service.ts and do the the right call from API.

Comment: By passing what you want as method arguments?

Comment: theValueEnteredByTheUser i can't pass it to service.ts

Comment: Do you know how to write a method taking an argument in TypeScript? Do these words make sense to you? Again, what have you tried? Why don't you post the code you tried?